# What are the benefits and disadvantages of creating a local IIS instance of a website under development?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis, iis-express

I created an instance of a website, say "website.xyzdev.net", on my local IIS. This replicates the uat instance and live instance like website.xyzuat.net and website.xyz.net respectively.

We are a team of 6 developers and I have this feeling that this way of having local instance on everyone's machine (instead of localhost:12345) will be beneficial, which was promptly questioned by my manager.

Could you please help me out if I am right or wrong, or is it something that totally depends on the person you are talking to.

Comment: I don't think there's any `right` or `wrong` answer to this question, it's too broad and opinion based. Perhaps if you asked a specific question it would be easier for someone to help